# when making a call to another class Android CPU usage goes way up

Tags: java, android, cpu, cpu-usage

When I try to make a call to another class say `DifficultyMenu.java` or `BasicsPractice.java`
using this method

```
/** makes these other classes usable in this class **/
DifficultyMenu DM = new DifficultyMenu();
BasicsPractice BP = new BasicsPractice();
```

the CPU usage on my Android app goes way up and the Application freezes and constantly has to suspend threads.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: What operations are you doing on these classes constructor?

Comment: nothing right from the beginning of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deleting extra class calls `DifficultyMenu DM = new DifficultyMenu();` in the classes specified